# SharePoint Emulator - How to Emulate SPServiceContext for getting Userprofiles

Tags: user-profile, unit-testing

I'm trying the SharePoint Emulator and wanted to emulate the access to a userprofile. But when trying to get SPServiceContext from an emulated site my SPServiceContext is null.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822928.aspx#BKMK_Emulated_SharePoint_types ServiceContext is not an emulated type. I'd be surprised if they supported anything beyond Site level objects.

Comment: Ok but that means that many solutiontypes can't be unittested.

Comment: If you are only using those tools (and not extending them) then yes, I would agree. But if you think about it, there is a LOT that falls into this category, like Search and MMS solutions. I think you need to look at your testing methods and tools and decide if it's worth your personal investment to develop the testing tools yourself. (Or test in another way.)